# Null Pointer Exception - Hadoop Mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, iterator, iterable

I am a beginner with Hadoop and Java, and I am writing Map, Reduce functions to cluster a set of latitudes and longitudes together into groups based on proximity, and set a magnitude (Number of lat,long pairs in a cluster) and a representative lat,long pair (As of now, it's the first lat,long pair encountered.)

Here's my code:

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import util.hashing.*;



public class LatLong {


 public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
    //private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);


    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] longLatArray = line.split(",");
        double longi = Double.parseDouble(longLatArray[0]);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(longLatArray[1]);
        //List<Double> origLatLong = new ArrayList<Double>(2);
        //origLatLong.add(lat);
        //origLatLong.add(longi);
        Geohash inst = Geohash.getInstance();
        //encode is the library's encoding function
        String hash = inst.encode(lat,longi);
        //Using the first 5 characters just for testing purposes
        //Need to find the right one later
        int accuracy = 4;
        //hash of the thing is shortened to whatever I figure out
        //to be the right size of each tile
        Text shortenedHash = new Text(hash.substring(0,accuracy));
        Text origHash = new Text(hash);
        context.write(shortenedHash, origHash);
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

     private IntWritable totalTileElementCount = new IntWritable();
     private Text latlongimag = new Text();
     private Text dataSeparator = new Text();

     @Override
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int elementCount = 0;
      boolean first = true;
      Iterator<Text> it= values.iterator();
      String lat = new String();
      String longi = new String();
      Geohash inst = Geohash.getInstance();

      while (it.hasNext()) {
       elementCount = elementCount+1;
       if(first)
       {
           lat = Double.toString((inst.decode(it.toString()))[0]);
           longi = Double.toString((inst.decode(it.toString()))[1]);
           first = false;

       }
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       String blah = it.next().toString();


      }
      totalTileElementCount.set(elementCount);
      //Geohash inst = Geohash.getInstance();

      String mag = totalTileElementCount.toString();

      latlongimag.set(lat+","+ longi +","+mag+",");
      dataSeparator.set("");
      context.write(latlongimag, dataSeparator );
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
    job.setJarByClass(LatLong.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

I'm getting a NPE. I don't know how I can test this, and I am not able to find the error in my code.

Hadoop Error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at util.hashing.Geohash.decode(Geohash.java:41)
    at org.myorg.LatLong$Reduce.reduce(LatLong.java:67)
    at org.myorg.LatLong$Reduce.reduce(LatLong.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

The decode function from the Geohash library returns an array of doubles. 
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time!

EDIT1 (after testing):

I have realized that the problem was with the fact that there needs to be an it.next().toString() in the reduce function and not just an it.toString(), but when I made this change and tested, I got this error, and I don't know why it should be coming when I am checking hasnext() in the while loop condition.

```
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: iterate past last value
    at    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.ReduceContext$ValueIterator.next(ReduceContext.java:159)
    at org.myorg.LatLong$Reduce.reduce(LatLong.java:69)
    at org.myorg.LatLong$Reduce.reduce(LatLong.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

EDIT2 (further testing): SOLUTION

I'm calling it.next() more than once, and being an iterator, that just causes it to go ahead, twice, and in the last iteration, it checks the condition and enters, but I'm then calling it.next() twice, which causes the problem as there is only one next element (The last one.)

Comment: i just have little java knowledge . if u are able to try narrow your exception search area we can try help better

Comment: So, when I analyze, this error probably means that decode returns a null pointer, which means that it.toString is not working s it's supposed to. This means either, my use of the iterator class is wrong, or the data which is fed into the reducer, is itself null. But, the mapper gives out orighash as its value which is indeed not null.

Comment: never used hadoop before but read about .. well as far as java is concerned depending on time available i would try these *manually feed data to iterator amd try *run with one single record as a test ;if one single works duplicate it and test *test 'security' issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still call `toString` on `it`, instead `it.next()`, so you should change

```
lat = Double.toString((inst.decode(it.toString()))[0]);
longi = Double.toString((inst.decode(it.toString()))[1]);
```

into

```
String cords = it.next().toString();
lat = Double.toString((inst.decode(cords))[0]);
longi = Double.toString((inst.decode(cords))[1]);
```

Don't make it `inst.decode(it.next().toString())` because it would call `it.next()` two times in one `while` iteration.

After that don't call `String blah = it.next().toString();` because you will get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: iterate past last value`, same reason as above.

And when you remove `String blah = it.next().toString();` remember that in case of `first = false` you will never enter `if(first)` and never call `String cords = it.next().toString();`
 so `it.hasNext()` will always return `true` and you will never leave the `while` loop, so add appropriate conditional statements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed it sometime back and ran it, and the job got stuck at reduce 51% hence the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089330/hadoop-maoreduce-job-stuck-at-map-100-reduce-51

Answer (score 0):

This means either your "it" is null or else you get null after decode.
Put null checks for them.

Comment: So, I realized that it should actually be it.next().toString() as that gives the object that I need to use and not just 'it'. So I'm testing that now. That could lead to an npe, right?

Comment: Yes that is the one causing problem. As a good practice, always have null checks in your code.